# VBA: Run-time error '1004': Method 'PivotTables' of object '_Worksheet' failed

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I am trying to write a macro that updates my pivot table when new data is put into the original table. I keep on receive an error and do not know how to fix it. Here's what I have so far.

```
Sub UpdatePivotTableRange() 
Dim Data_Sheet As Worksheet 
Dim Pivot_Sheet As Worksheet 
Dim StartPoint As Range 
Dim PivotName As String 
Dim NewRange As String 
Dim LastCol As Long 
Dim lastRow As Long 

Set Data_Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data insert") 
Set Pivot_Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CC_Users") 

PivotName = PivotTable6 Data_Sheet.Activate 
Set StartPoint = Data_Sheet.Range("A1") 

LastCol = StartPoint.End(xlToRight).Column 
DownCell = StartPoint.End(xlDown).Row 

Set DataRange = Data_Sheet.Range(StartPoint, Cells(DownCell, LastCol)) 
NewRange = Data_Sheet.Name & "!" & DataRange.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) 

Pivot_Sheet.PivotTables (PivotName) 
ChangePivotCache.ActiveWorkbook PivotCaches.Create SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=NewRange Pivot_Sheet.PivotTables(PivotName).RefreshTable

Pivot_Sheet.Activate MsgBox "Your Pivot table is now updated" End Sub
```

---

Thank you

Comment: Are you just trying to refresh a pivot? If so, use `RefreshAll`

Comment: No I'm trying to make it so it's automated. zero touch refresh when new data is put into the table.

Comment: So call the command when the table changes with worksheet_change

Comment: Will you be pasting new entries into the table (whole rows at a time) or will you be keying in values in a row cell by cell?

Comment: I will be copy and pasting into the table. Whole rows at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This needs to be pasted in *VBE* on the sheet that holds your table that will be changed.

As is, this will refresh **every** pivot table (along with pivot charts) that exist on your workbook when **ANY** cell on your sheet with the table is changed.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

Msgbox "All Pivots Refreshed"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm sorry if I was confusing with how I wrote my question, this is my first post and didn't know how to word it properly. This helps. Thanks

Comment: I also recommend that you visit the [tour] page and [ask] a question page

Comment: I put in the code you gave me. Is there a way to make the message box not show up every time I press on a cell on the data table. I will look at the "How to Ask a question page" for future reference.